# Different versions of Haazinu song structure

Tags: history, song-poetry, text, haazinu

I have heard (in conversation) that there are early Torah scrolls, or sources mentioning this, that don't follow the two-column Haazinu that is now universally written; but rather, something similar to the Az Yashir 'brick like' structure.

Could someone locate this source please? If it is indeed the case, why was it different? Was it a legitimate way of writing the song? And is there a reason why it is no longer adopted?

Comment: A few very very very old Ashkenazi scrolls are like this. I think Penkower has an article about it.

Comment: Not sure if it’s related; but, I just learned in Masekhet Rosh Hashanah (31A) that there are slight differences amongst the poseqim as to how to divide the `Aliyot for Parashat Ha’azinu.

Comment: @DoubleAA, do all scrolls that do the two-column structure do it full justified, four straight vertical edges (which lead to very squished and stretched sections)? Or have there been other customs, say ragged toward the center? Is there a source on this?

Comment: @MichoelR Ragged towards the center used to be standard. Justifying the insides is a modern "chumra" based on a Ran about how to do the 10 sons of haman (even there it's probably not what the Ran meant)

Comment: @DoubleAA Is there a good source for these kind of historical changes in sifrei Torah, maybe with pictures?

Comment: @MichoelR Changes to sifrei torah?!?!?!?!?!?!? Not that I'm aware of. Your best bet may be an academic article trying to date a scroll, like Penkower's in Textus 21. But even that will be limited by issues presenting in that particular specimen.

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, like, how did you know that "Ragged towards the center used to be standard."

Comment: @Michoel Experience?